# Unlock my iPhone

Tags: backup, iphone, unlock

I forgot the PIN code of my iPhone 5S; I tried many times to unlock it and I finished to block it indefinitely. I haven't got any backup files and before resetting it I want to recover all my photos. Is there a way to unlock it or at least save my photos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306) there are a few ways to unlock iPhone. Maybe some of these are fit for you